# Recovering MySQl database from .frm, ibdata and ib_logfile

Tags: mysql, recover

I have .frm, ibdata and ib_logfile from my previous version of MySQl and now I have shifting to a newer version. Unfortunately, I donot have the previous version installed so I cannot take the dump and import into the new MySQl version.

Please suggest some way to get these databases running in the newer MySQL version. I have all the required files from the previous MSQl.

Comment: I believe Emil's suggestion will work in case you had only InnoDB tables.  For MyISAM tables, you need the .frm, .myi and .myd files for each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it may seem trivial. But since I had saved the entire MySQL folder present in Program Files from my previous installation. I found out that I could still use that folder to run the previous MySQL installation without any changes or reinstallation (it seems MySQl works like Linux softwares). And now I am using mysqldump to create the dump and then will import it into the new MySQL version.

Answer (score 2):

It's really dangerous to do this, so just do it on a copy of the files (and try hard to use the exact same version of MySQL):

- Make sure the MySQL service is not running
- Remove the ib_logfile (it is not needed)
- Put the files in place in the MySQL datadir
- Start your server and check the logfiles.
- Check that everything is working.

Comment: This did not work. Though it recognizes the databases and the tables lying in the data dir, it cannot read the data in these tables. I get this error when I try to read some info from a table using sql query:

ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file: '.\db_name\table_name.frm'