# MySQL restore from ibdata, ib_logfile with schema name ndbinfo

Tags: mysql, service

We had a breach into our system and this is not starting now.
Logs are empty.
Any help is appreciated!

Because of the errors in the screenshot provided the mysql server is not starting.

I'm trying to restore the database from ibdata, ib_logfile files.
All tutorials to restore this are based on schema folders full of frm files.
There is only one shchema name ndbinfo that contains frm.
While accessing ndbinfo mysql says this is not recognized schema name for INNODB.
Can anyone elaborate why I do not have other schema names, but ndbinfo. This not seems like supposed to be, I imagine there should be folders with schema names I had on my database.

I've read about ndb_restore, though it seems to be associated with mysql cluster which I even don't have installed on my system. ndb_restore is unrecognized command.

Comment: What does the log tell you? If the shell tells you that something was written to the log, there should be a log....

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking at var/log/mysql.log , mysql.err - empty. 
Can we focus on the screenshot I've included? There must be something done to corrupt database... something with limits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering MySQl database from .frm, ibdata and ib\_logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055545/recovering-mysql-database-from-frm-ibdata-and-ib-logfile)